# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - HBase indexing data

Tags: java

I am parsing a pdf and storing title, author etc. in variables, and I need to index the values in hbase. So I am getting datas of hbase table from the variables that I created in the project. Program shows me NullPointerException error when I use the variables for indexing in hbase table.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:154)
    at testSolr.Testt.Parsing(Testt.java:50)
    at testSolr.Testt.main(Testt.java:94)
```

I tried two different types and none of them worked.

```
String title = new String(metadata.get("title"));
```

and

```
String title = metadata.get("title");
```

Here is the parts of my code(I wrote significant parts.):

```
          Random rand = new Random();
          int min=1, max=5000;
          int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

           //parsing part
           String title = new String(metadata.get("title"));
           String nPage = new String(metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPage"));
           String author = new String(metadata.get("Author"));
           String content = new String(handler.toString());

          //hbase part(the part where I am getting the error.)
          Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(randomNumber));
          p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("title"),Bytes.toBytes(title));
          p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("author"),Bytes.toBytes(author));
          p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("pageNumber"),Bytes.toBytes(nPage));
          p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
                  Bytes.toBytes("content"),Bytes.toBytes(content));
          hTable.put(p);
```

Should I make variables null in the beginning of parsing? I think that does not make any sense. What should I do to fix the error?

Update:
Full code

public static String location = "/home/alican/Downloads/solr-4.10.2/example/solr/senior/PDFs/solr-word.pdf";

```
public static void Parsing(String location) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SolrServerException {
  // random number generator for ids
  Random rand = new Random();
  int min=1, max=5000;
  int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  // random number generator for ids ends
  // pdf Parser
  BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
  FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(location);
  Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
  ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
  PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();
  pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);      
   String title = new String(metadata.get("title"));
   String nPage = metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPage");
   String author = new String(metadata.get("Author"));
   String content = new String(handler.toString());

  System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));
  System.out.println("Number of Page(s): " + metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPages"));
  System.out.println("Author(s): " + metadata.get("Author"));

  System.out.println("Content of the PDF :" + handler.toString());
  // pdf Parser ends
  // solr Indexing
  SolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient(url); 
  SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();


  doc.addField("id", randomNumber);
  doc.addField("author", author);
  doc.addField("title", title);
  doc.addField("pageNumber", nPage);
  doc.addField("content", content);

  server.add(doc);
  System.out.println("solr commiiitt......");
  server.commit();
  // solr Indexing ends
  // hbase Indexing
  Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
  HTable hTable = new HTable(config, "books");
  Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(randomNumber));
  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
          Bytes.toBytes("title"),Bytes.toBytes(title));
  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
          Bytes.toBytes("author"),Bytes.toBytes(author));
  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
          Bytes.toBytes("pageNumber"),Bytes.toBytes(nPage));
  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
          Bytes.toBytes("content"),Bytes.toBytes(content));
  hTable.put(p);
  System.out.println("hbase commiiitttt..");
  hTable.close();
  // hbase Indexing ends
```

}

Output of title, author, number of page and content:

```
Title: solr-word
Number of Page(s): 1
Author(s): Grant Ingersoll
Content of the PDF :
This is a test of PDF and Word extraction in Solr, it is only a test.  Do not panic.
```

HBase part assumes that variable of nPage is null. Actually it is not. Value of nPage is 1.

```
p.add(Bytes.toBytes("book"),
              Bytes.toBytes("pageNumber"),Bytes.toBytes(nPage));
```

Solution:

metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPage") returns null when it is assigned to a variable for some reason. I realized that it is because of parser. I changed my parser and there is no any null variable anymore. 
- Apache PDFBox(my new parser) is better than Apache Tika(my old parser).

Comment: What `metadata` is ? please update you question, so we can propose a proper solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `metadata.get("title")` is returning null, therefore, a NullPointerException is thrown. See [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)) for more details.

Comment: Nothing is null, but hbase part assumes that nPage is null even it is not.

Comment: `String title = new String(metadata.get("title"));`, what's the value you're getting for `title` ? Look the stacktrace, is pretty clear where the problem is:  `testSolr.Testt.Parsing(Testt.java:50)`

Comment: The value of title is : "solr-word". 
I did the same thing for nPage and it returned null when I wanted to see output of nPage. But if I write like this   `System.out.println("Number of Page(s): " + metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPages"));`  I can see output as 1 which is correct(the pdf has only 1 page). Number of Page(s): 1

Comment: I changed my parser, and now there is no any null variable. I was using Apache Tİka, I now am using Apache PDFBox. Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as correct answer, it can help someone else in the future.